# I can't update MiKTeX package-manifests.ini invalid value definition

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

I get an error in TeX Studio for File `polynom.sty' not found.

When I open MiKTeX Console to Check for Updates or Update package database I get an error message, then sometimes MiKTeX Console crashes.

file="C:\Users\fisdu\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\package-manifests.ini", line="145760", error="invalid value definition"

line 145760 is blank
run[]=texmf/fonts/tfm/google/noto/NotoSans-ExtraCondensedLight-lf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
run[]=texmf/fonts/

[varwidth]
copyrightOwner=Donald Arseneau

The copied Error Details:
GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION
Date: 2020-01-11 15:03:12
MiKTeX: 2.9.7250
OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 17763
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Users\fisdu\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheck: not yet
LastUpdate: not yet
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\fisdu\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\fisdu\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\Users\fisdu\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9
Root3: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root4: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\fisdu\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\fisdu\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\fisdu\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Invokers: non-existing/explorer

Warning: the following problems were detected:
  1: Never checked for updates.

ERROR DETAILS
Program: C:\Users\fisdu\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-console.exe
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Cfg\Cfg.cpp:1052
Error: A MiKTeX configuration file could not be loaded.
Details: 
  file: C:\Users\fisdu\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\package-manifests.ini
  line: 145760
  error: invalid value definition

Comment: Line 145760 of file `package-manifests.ini`) is not valid. A similar issue has been reported in the past: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/290